# Nuget Implementation in an Enterprise Application Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, nuget

This is much of an architectural level question where I am stuck at. I was planning to implement nuget onto our enterprise project to get rid of multiple levels of deployment/re-building of projects. Here is the Project structure:

1. Framework (class lib solution): It is referenced in every other solution
2. ParentClient(WPF App Solution): It is the host client, it can contain many other module inside it which are different solutions as (3). This also uses Framework dlls
3. MyClient(WPF solution): This client is a module which also uses Framework dlls

Now presently whenever there is a change in Framework's dlls, the corresponding other solutions/projects must be updated, since in the actual deployment environment(a windows machine/ Client Machine) all the dlls resides in the same bin folder. If I do not update the framework dlls, then the present module won't function, and if I do, it might impact the existing application which do not require the latest framework update although due to the latest changes, it somehow breaks the current functioning. (Remember: This issue is due to the fact that in the ParentClient, we have multiple modules say MyClient, YourClient etc)

I would like to know whether or not we can use Nuget or does Nuget will might help me in resolving the issue...???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NuGet is the way to go. You can set up a very simple NuGet Server by simply creating an empty MVC application and then getting the NuGet Server project template from... nuget :)

An even easier solution, is to simply host your NuGet packages from a network share. You can then keep all versions of your dll's there, and address them from your CI/Build server. Nuget supports adding a network share as a source, and this is common practice

Comment: Yes I understand about implementing the Nuget server, BUT my question is HOW will two different versions of Framework dlls would solve the issue when one of my module requires one version's functionality and other requires the latest's one?? 

since in the actual Client Machine's Bin folder, I can just have one dll of the same name at one point of time..